# EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT deprecated в Android Oreo - чем заменить

Tags: java, android

Собственно говоря весь вопрос вынесен в заголовок.

Есть такой код, который при первом запуске приложения устанавливает shortcut/ссылку на приложение в Home экране.

```
private void doFirstRun() {
    if (PrefsFragment.isFirstRun(this)) { //add shortcut to app in home screen
        final Intent shortcutIntent = MyActivity.getStartIntent(this.getApplicationContext());
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        final Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, this.getString(R.string.myapp));
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.myapp));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so don't duplicate
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
        PrefsFragment.setFirstRun(this, false);
    }
}
```

В Android Oreo - код размечается как *устаревший/deprecated*, хотя конечно же работает.

Слегка погуглил, но ничего толком не нашел. Без особой надежды, на русский SO таки спрошу - чем заменить этот код для Android API >= 26?

Comment: не имел дела с шорткатами, но подозреваю что вам копать в сторону ShortcutInfo.Builder и ShortcutManager

Comment: UPD: Таки да, прям в доке годный гайд https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html

Comment: Если не затруднит - оформите ответ как положено